# Почему LSTM идет раньше self-attention?

Tags: машинное-обучение, nlp, deep-learning

В большом количестве примеров для задачи классификации текстов слой self-attention идет после слоя RNN/LSTM/GRU. Чем может быть мотивирован данный порядок? Кажется, что self-attention обладает преимуществом при обработке последовательностей (особенно длинных), что позволит вначале перевзвесить эмбеддинги слов, а затем уже обработать их с помощью слоев с памятью.

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но вряд ли вам тут кто-то ответит, это надо куда-нибудь в сообщество ods.ai с такими вопросами )